# how to change color when click active button php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to toggle active button when i click for active and inactive

```
$('.factive').click(function(){

  var factiveId = $(this).attr('id');
  $.post('controller/ajax-product-active.php?factiveId='+factiveId,
  {},function(data)
    {  
      $('#product-active').html(data);
    });
  });
```

ajax-product-active.php

```
if ($csrow['status']=='Active') {

    $update_status = mysqli_query($conn,"update products set status = 'Deactive' where id = '{$factiveId}'");

    echo "<a id='$csrow[id]' class='factive' style='cursor: pointer;'  onclick='productActive($csrow[id])'>
                    <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true'style='color:red' title='Deactive'></i></a>";

}elseif ($csrow['status']=='Deactive') {

    $update_status = mysqli_query($conn,"update products set status = 'Active' where id = '{$factiveId}'");

    echo "<a id='$csrow[id]' class='factive' style='cursor: pointer;'  onclick='productActive($csrow[id])'>
                    <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true'style='color:#12bc00' title='Active'></i></a>";
}
```

This code is running successfully but color is changing only first.

Comment: you should return data in PHP json and do html changes on javascript

Comment: Is classes `"factive"` and `"pactive"` different?